# ItemSelectionModel for custom QAstractTableModel

Tags: python, qml, qtquick2

I have this `main.py` with a custom `QAbstractTableModel`:

```
import sys
import signal


from PyQt6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel


class InstalledPkgsModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(InstalledPkgsModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

            return value

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        try:
            return len(self._data[0])
        # If there are no installed mods in the prefix
        except IndexError:
            return 1


# Make app respond to Ctrl-C
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)  # type: ignore

# Populate manage table view installed packages
data = [
    ["git", "", "common", "1.0"],
    ["distutils", "", "common", "1.0"],
    ["bsa", "", "common", "0.4"],
    ["nexus", "", "common", "1.0"],
    ["fallout_4", "", "common", "0.1"],
]
installed_pkgs_model = InstalledPkgsModel(data)
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("installed_pkgs_model", installed_pkgs_model)

engine.load("main.qml")

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I'd like to set something up where I can select rows in the `TableView` that's using this model. I currently have this `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 700
    title: "Portmod"

    TableView {
        width: 1000
        height: 700
        id: installedPkgsTable
        columnSpacing: 1
        rowSpacing: 1
        clip: true

        model: installed_pkgs_model

        selectionModel: ItemSelectionModel {
            model: installed_pkgs_model
        }

        delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 300
            implicitHeight: 50
            color: selected ? "blue" : "lightgray"

            required property bool selected

            Text {
                text: display
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The problem is, it doesn't work. Clicking on a row does nothing, and it sometimes outputs this:

```
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsAboutToBeRemoved(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsAboutToBeRemoved(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsAboutToBeInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsAboutToBeInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsAboutToBeMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsAboutToBeMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::layoutAboutToBeChanged(QList<QPersistentModelIndex>,QAbstractItemModel::LayoutChangeHint)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::layoutChanged(QList<QPersistentModelIndex>,QAbstractItemModel::LayoutChangeHint)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::modelReset()
```

Comment: This is not reproducible since we don't know what `Atom` is please share an MRE.

Comment: You also didn't showed how you expose the model to QML

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I've updated the main post to be a MRE.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like registering it via `setContextProperty()` has some weird behaviour. It is also not a recommended way to expose Python / C++ to QML.

Use instead:
*PySide6:*

```py
QtQml.qmlRegisterSingletonInstance(
    QAbstractTableModel, "com.example.model", 1, 0, "PyModel", model
)
```

*PyQt6:*

```py
qmlRegisterSingletonInstance(
    "com.example.model", 1, 0, "InstalledPkgsModel", installed_pkgs_model
)
```

Then in QML import this as per normal:

```
import com.example.model 1.0
```

And use it like this:
*PySide6:*

```
model: PyModel
```

*PyQt6:*

```py
model: InstalledPkgsModel
```

> Clicking on a row does nothing.

If you want to be able to select you can use [`SelectionRectangle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-selectionrectangle.html#details)

Comment: Registering it via the singleton does get rid of the errors, so thanks for that. I thought just doing [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#selecting-items) would make selection work. SelectionRectangle appears to be for dragging a selection rectangle, but it even says:
```Note: A SelectionRectangle itself is not shown as part of a selection. Only the delegates (like topLeftHandle and bottomRightHandle) are used. You should also consider rendering the TableView delegate as selected.```

Comment: @PopeRigby Sorry can't understand you..

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll try to rephrase. The link I posted gives the instructions for implementing selection. I did those things, and selection doesn't work. From looking at `SelectionRectangle`, it's just for being able to drag a rectangle across multiple cells, but selection still needs to be implemented for the cells to be highlighted. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @PopeRigby I suggest you to open a new question, with the new code. And generally try to address only one issue in a question.